# CakePHP call to undefined method stdClass::read() error

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP and I'm still learning the basics, through working in a live project and taking help from the CakePHP documentations when necessary. Currently, I'm having the following problem : I've recently changed my database table name and structure, so I was forced to change my view, controller and model names. After changing names, whenever I run the index.ctp page, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::read() in C:\wamp\www\sdb\app\controllers
\home_loan_distributions_details_controller.php on line 32
```

Previously, my view folder was named `home_loan_distributions`, now it's renamed to `home_loan_distributions_details`.

My previous controller name was `home_loan_distributions_controller.php` and current name is `home_loan_distributions_details_controller.php`. The codes:

```
class HomeLoanDistributionsDetailsController extends AppController {

        var $name = 'HomeLoanDistributionsDetails';

        function index() {
            $user = $this->Session->read('User');
            $user_role = $user['User']['user_role_id'];
            $actions = $this->Session->read('actions');
            $display_actions = array();

            foreach ($actions as $action) {
                array_push($display_actions, $action['pm_controller_actions']['name']);
            }
            $this->set('display_actions', $display_actions);
            $this->set('user_role', $user_role);


            $branch_id = 18;
            $this->set('branch_id', $branch_id);
            $conditions = array('branch_id' => $branch_id);


            $this->set('HomeLoanDistributionsDetails', $this->paginate($conditions));
            $this->HomeLoanDistributionDetail->Branch->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('BranchDetailInformation', $this->HomeLoanDistributionDetail->Branch->read(array('Branch.id', 'Branch.name', 'RegionalOffice.name', 'DistrictOffice.name', 'SubDistrictOffice.name', 'ClusterOffice.name'), $branch_id));
        }
```

My model was previously named `home_loan_distribution.php` and now it's named `home_loan_distribution_detail.php`. The codes:

```
class HomeLoanDistributionDetail extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'HomeLoanDistributionDetail';
    var $actsAs = array('Logable' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'userKey' => 'user_id',
            'change' => 'list', // options are 'list' or 'full'
            'description_ids' => TRUE // options are TRUE or FALSE
    ));
    var $validate = array(
        'entry_date' => array(
            'rule' => 'date',
            'message' => 'Enter a valid date',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        ),
        'branch_id' => array('numeric'),
        'customer_id' => array('numeric'),
        'loan_amount' => array('numeric'),
        'service_charge' => array('numeric'),
        'security' => array('numeric'),
        'loan_taken_term' => array('numeric'),
        'purpose_id' => array('numeric'),
        'installment_amount' => array('numeric'),
        'installment_service_charge' => array('numeric'),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Branch' => array(
            'className' => 'Branch',
            'foreignKey' => 'branch_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => 'id,name',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

    function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {

      $recursive = 0;

      $group = $fields = array('branch_id', 'entry_date');
      $order = array('entry_date DESC');
      $limit = 4;
      $this->paginateCount($conditions);
      return $this->find('all', compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'recursive', 'group'));
      }

      function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {

      $recursive = 0;
      $group = $fields = array('branch_id', 'entry_date');
      $order = array('entry_date DESC');
      $results = $this->find('all', compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive', 'group'));
      return count($results);
      }


}
```

What my guess is: probably I messed up the naming conventions while renaming everything. The problem is definitely within this line in the controller:

```
$this->set('BranchDetailInformation',
$this->HomeLoanDistributionDetail->Branch->read(array('Branch.id', 'Branch.name',
'RegionalOffice.name', 'DistrictOffice.name', 'SubDistrictOffice.name', 'ClusterOffice.name'),
$branch_id));
```

Whenever I comment out this line, I stop getting the above mentioned error message and my view page loads (although that still have some data missing - because I need those Branch related data to be displayed in my view.)
I can't figure out what exactly my problem is, but at least I know where it is. I need someone to pinpoint it.

My CakePHP version is 1.2.5, PHP version - 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem seemed to be related to my `'className' => 'Branch'` element of the `Branch` array used in my model, since the `stdClass::read()` method is related to classes and not models. But I discovered that the problem was elsewhere. This error was part of that problem, but it itself is not the actual problem.

I figured out this morning that my Model name is `HomeLoanDistributionDetail`, but my table name is `home_loan_distributions_details` (because someone else has changed the table name). CakePHP convention requires corresponding table name to be plural and model class name to be singular and CamelCased.

Quoting from the [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html):

> Model class names are **singular** and **CamelCased**. Person, BigPerson, and ReallyBigPerson are all examples of conventional model names.
>
> Table names corresponding to CakePHP models are **plural** and **underscored**. The underlying tables for the above mentioned models would be people, big_people, and really_big_people, respectively.

Considering the above convention, I just had to rename my model class name from `HomeLoanDistributionDetail` to `HomeLoanDistributionsDetail`, in order to match with the table name `home_loan_distributions_details`. Also, I had to change the model file name from `home_loan_distribution_detail.php` to `home_loan_distributions_detail.php`.

After doing that, I stopped getting the error and I was successful in retrieving data from table and viewing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `read` for model.If you want to find some model data then try with -

```
$this->set('BranchDetailInformation', $this->HomeLoanDistributionDetail->Branch->find('all', $consitions);
```

`$conditions` will be the array of all requirements you want to provide. See the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#retrieving-your-data) for more info.

Comment: `$this->HomeLoanDistributionDetail->Branch` I think `Branch` is being identified as a class here, not as a model. Maybe that's why I can use the `read()` method? Similar codes exist in other parts of the project, and I've seen them write like this and those bits are working fine. `Branch` here is not a model, I suppose.

Comment: can you add that code?? `Branch` is an instance of model. You also have defined the relation. `read` is a method of `Session` component not Model.